# Given $\phi\sqsubset\psi$, find $\sigma$ such that $\phi\sqsubset\sigma\sqsubset\psi$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working through Van Dalen's *Logic and Structure* (fifth edition, 2013) independently, and have gotten stuck on problem 2.3.14(i), on p.28.

The author defines: $\phi\sqsubset\psi$ if and only if $\vDash\phi\to\psi$ and $\not\vDash\psi\to\phi$. The question, then, is:

> For each $\phi$, $\psi$ such that $\phi\sqsubset\psi$, find $\sigma$ with $\phi\sqsubset\sigma\sqsubset\psi$.

As I understand this, we need $\vDash\phi\to\sigma$ and $\vDash\sigma\to\psi$, which means there can be no valuation $v$ where $[[\phi]]_v=1$ and $[[\sigma]]_v=0$ or where $[[\sigma]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=0$. Also, we need $\not\vDash\psi\to\sigma$ and $\not\vDash\sigma\to\phi$, which means there must be a valuation $v$ where $[[\psi]]_v=1$ and $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, and a $v$ where $[[\sigma]]_v=1$ and $[[\phi]]_v=0$.

So:

- if $[[\phi]]_v=[[\psi]]_v=1$, then $[[\sigma]]_v=1$, because $\vDash\phi\to\sigma$
- if $[[\phi]]_v=[[\psi]]_v=0$, then $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, because $\vDash\sigma\to\psi$
- if $[[\phi]]_v=0$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$, then $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, because otherwise there would be no valuation $v$ where $[[\psi]]_v=1$ and $[[\sigma]]_v=0$.

But then there is the case where $[[\phi]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=0$. If $[[\sigma]]_v=1$, then there is no valuation $v$ such that $[[\sigma]]_v=1$ and $[[\phi]]_v=0$. But if $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, then $\vDash\phi\to\sigma$ does not hold.

Based on my understanding, then, there can be no such $\sigma$, because its value cannot be determined in the case where $[[\phi]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=0$. So what am I missing here?

---

**Edit:** as @mohottnad pointed out, the case where $[[\phi]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=0$ cannot occur because $\phi\sqsubset\psi$ is given. But then $[[\phi]]_v=0$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$ is a problem: if $[[\sigma]]_v=1$, then we don't have $\not\vDash\psi\to\sigma$, but if $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, then we don't have $\not\vDash\sigma\to\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your third bullet point, where you write:

> If $[[\phi]]_v=0$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$, then $[[\sigma]]_v=0$, because otherwise there would be no valuation $v$ where $[[\psi]]_v=1$ and $[[\sigma]]_v=0$.

This is not right; in these bullet points, you are considering a *specific* choice of valuation $v$. Even if $[[\sigma]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$ for *this choice* of $v$, it is entirely possible that there exists another valuation $w$ such that $[[\sigma]]_w=0$ and $[[\psi]]_w=1$. Perhaps an example might make things clearer; suppose $\phi=\bot$ and $\psi=\top$. Then $[[\phi]]_v=0$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$ for *any* valuation $v$. Can you therefore think of a choice of $\sigma$ such that $\phi\sqsubset\sigma\sqsubset\psi$?

> For example, take $\sigma=p$  for any propositional variable $p$. Then $[[\sigma]]_v=0$ whenever $v(p)=0$ and $[[\sigma]]_v=1$ whenever $v(p)=1$.

As a final remark, the situation you describe in the paragraph following your three bullet points – ie of having $[[\phi]]_v=1$ and $[[\psi]]_v=0$ for some valuation $v$ – is impossible, since we have $\phi\sqsubset\psi$ by hypothesis. Do you think you are now equipped to tackle the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I spent so much time on the abstract part of the question, that I forgot to consider a concrete example. So if I understand correctly, we could write any proposition that is not *always* valued 0 for $\sigma$ in this example? I think I'll be able to solve the problem, if I start with some more concrete examples, and then look for generalisations.

Comment: dear @GaiusPetronius yep, that's exactly right! :) (any $\sigma$ that is not always valued $0$ *and also* not always valued $1$.) that sounds like an excellent approach to solving the problem!

Comment: Cool. Because if $\sigma$ is *always* valued 1, then $\vDash\top\to\sigma$, which is not allowed. If I don't post about it again in the next few days, consider the problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's exactly right. good luck, and please feel free to comment if you have any more questions! :)

Comment: I am not sure whether it is the right approach but I made a truth table to see for which valuations of $\varphi, \sigma,$ and $\psi$, it is true that $\models \varphi \rightarrow \sigma, \models \sigma \rightarrow \psi , \models \varphi \rightarrow \psi$. I found that this is true in four cases:
 1)v($\varphi$)=v($\psi$)=v($\sigma$)=0 
2) v($\varphi$)=v($\sigma$)=0 and v($\psi$)=1
3)v($\varphi$)=0 and v($\psi$)=v($\sigma$)=1 
4) v($\varphi$)=v($\psi$)=v($\sigma$)=1 
How do I proceed to get a choice of $\sigma$? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

There seems no such case as [[ϕ]]v=1 and [[ψ]]v=0 you need to worry about since you have premise below. Although your book may use a certain logic system, but intuitively this case violates the usual material conditional rules, you need to use your logic system's rules to rule out such a pathological case formally.

> For each $\phi$, $\psi$ such that $\phi\sqsubset\psi$,

Comment: Right, but then the case where $[[\phi]]_v=0$ and $[[\psi]]_v=1$ causes problems, as I added in my edit on the original question.

Comment: @GaiusPetronius this is essentially filling out truth table in standard propositional calculus, you seemed lost in the new fancy notations maze. Now I saw you're clear, good progress.